# Django REST API Changed SSL certificate and now unresponsive

Tags: django, ssl, ssl-certificate, mod-wsgi

I'm developing a REST API using Django's REST API framework. I've been running a modwsgi server to test the API over HTTPS.

```
python manage.py runmodwsgi --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8002 --https-port 8001 --ssl-certificate /path/to/cert/and/key --server-name FQDN
```

The normal behavior is this output, followed by no command prompt:

```
Successfully ran command.
Server URL         : http://FQDN:8002/
Server URL (HTTPS) : https://FQDN:8001/
Server Root        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8002:1005
Server Conf        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8002:1005/httpd.conf
Error Log File     : /tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8002:1005/error_log
Request Capacity   : 5 (1 process * 5 threads)
Request Timeout    : 60 (seconds)
Queue Backlog      : 100 (connections)
Queue Timeout      : 45 (seconds)
Server Capacity    : 20 (event/worker), 20 (prefork)
Server Backlog     : 500 (connections)
Locale Setting     : en_US.UTF-8
```

This has been working fine up until I needed to change my certificate. The original certificate had the wrong FQDN and presented security warnings whenever an HTTPS request was made to the server. So, I made a request for a new certificate and had it signed, this time with the appropriate  FQDN. I now run the same command with the new .key and .crt specified:

```
python manage.py runmodwsgi --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8002 --https-port 8001 --ssl-certificate /path/to/new/cert/and/key --server-name FQDN
```

And instead I receive the modwsgi output followed by a command prompt, meaning **the process halted!**

```
Successfully ran command.
Server URL         : http://FQDN:8002/
Server URL (HTTPS) : https://FQDN:8001/
Server Root        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8002:1005
Server Conf        : /tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8002:1005/httpd.conf
Error Log File     : /tmp/mod_wsgi-0.0.0.0:8002:1005/error_log
Request Capacity   : 5 (1 process * 5 threads)
Request Timeout    : 60 (seconds)
Queue Backlog      : 100 (connections)
Queue Timeout      : 45 (seconds)
Server Capacity    : 20 (event/worker), 20 (prefork)
Server Backlog     : 500 (connections)
Locale Setting     : en_US.UTF-8
khandy@server:-$     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<THIS SHOULDNT HAPPEN
```

I'm at a loss. To me changing the certificate should have no effect on execution, but now the server will not persist!

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the error log? There should be something in the error log. If not try adding both the options '--log-to-terminal' and '--startup-log'. BTW, you are better off using the mod_wsgi mailing list rather than SO for questions about mod_wsgi-express.

Comment: Good call! I was able to see within the error log that the .key file and .crt file did not match. Not good, but easily solvable!

Comment: BTW. Most recent mod_wsgi-express versions allow you to use separate ``--ssl-certificate-file`` and ``--ssl-certificate-key-file`` if single combined option is confusing or prevents you from having them in separate directories.